# retrieve elements from two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quiz with 3-4 answer choices. 
How can I retrieve them if the answer choices varies per question ?
I know code if I have the same number of choices for every question.

My code:

```
    var answerArray = [
        ["black", "green", "yellow", "orange"], 
        ["big","small","long"], 
             ];

     function wait() {
     questionCounter < 1 ? 
        (questionCounter++,

        generateQuestions(),
              }; 

    function generateQuestions() {
        gameHTML = "<p class='text-center'>" + questionArray   [questionCounter] + "</p><p class='first-answer answer'>A. " + answerArray[questionCounter][0] + "</p><p class='answer'>B. "+answerArray[questionCounter][1]+"</p><p class='answer'>C. "+answerArray[questionCounter][2]+"</p><p class='answer'>D. "+answerArray[questionCounter][3]+"</p>";
$("#mainArea").html(gameHTML);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the length of the answers array for that question and iterate over each answer:

```
function generateQuestions() {
    const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    let gameHTML = "<p class='text-center'>;
    // iterate over each answer:
    answerArray[questionCounter].forEach((answer, index) => {
       const letter = letters[index] + '.';
       gameHTML += "<p class='answer'>" + letter + answer + "</p>"
    })
    $("#mainArea").html(gameHTML);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a loop for this even when you know the number, just to make the code more maintainable (like, so you don't have to rewrite the logic in case the number changes.)

For example, you could dynamically make a list of questions like this:

```js
    const questionsArray = [
        ["What's my favorite color?"], 
        ["Describe my favorite toy."]
     ];

    const mainContainer = document.querySelector("#mainContainer");
    for(let i = 0; i < questionsArray.length; i++){

      // Makes a node to hold the question text
      let qTextNode = document.createTextNode(questionsArray[i]);

      // Makes a paragraph element to display the question text in
      let qParagraph = document.createElement("p");

      // Makes a div element to hold this question and all its possible answers
      let qContainer = document.createElement("div");

      // Gives the container some distinguishing attributes
      qContainer.classList.add("question");
      qContainer.id = (i + 1);

      // Puts the text in the paragraph
      qParagraph.appendChild(qTextNode);

      // Puts the paragraph in the container
      qContainer.appendChild(qParagraph);

      // Adds the container (and everything inside it) to the page
      mainContainer.appendChild(qContainer);

    }
    // Prints out the HTML we just created
    console.log(mainContainer.outerHTML.split("><").join(">\n<"));
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer"></div>
```

It may not look like much when you run the snippet, but as you can see in the console, you now have an organized structure for all your answer choices to live in. Later javascript code can come along and find specific elements on your page, as can CSS styles.

Here's a juiced-up version that adds the answer text for each question. For this, we need a loop inside a loop (since each question has several answer choices that we want to add dynamically):

```js
const questionsArray = [
        ["What's my favorite color?"], 
        ["Describe my favorite toy."]
      ];
const answersArray = [
        ["black", "green", "yellow", "orange"], 
        ["big","small","long"], 
      ];

    // Stuff you saw in the previous snippet
    const mainContainer = document.querySelector("#mainContainer");
    for(let i = 0; i < questionsArray.length; i++){
      let qTextNode = document.createTextNode(questionsArray[i]);
      let qParagraph = document.createElement("p");
      let qContainer = document.createElement("div");
      qContainer.classList.add("question");
      qContainer.id = (i + 1);
      qParagraph.appendChild(qTextNode);
      qContainer.appendChild(qParagraph);
    
      // Makes an "ordered list" element to hold the choices
      let aList = document.createElement("ol");
      
      // Letters array will be used for item IDs
      let letters = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J".split(",");          

      // A nested loop to add the choices
      for(let j = 0; j < answersArray[i].length; j++){

        // Makes a textNode to hold the current choice
        let aTextNode = document.createTextNode(answersArray[i][j]);

        // Makes a list-item element to display the choice text in
        let aItem = document.createElement("li");

        // Gives the item an id using question number & answer letter
        aItem.id = (i + 1) + letters[j];

        // Puts the choice text in the item
        aItem.appendChild(aTextNode);

        // Puts the item in the list
        aList.appendChild(aItem);
      }

    // Done looping through choices, this adds the list to the question container
    qContainer.appendChild(aList);

  // And... we're back to stuff from the previous snippet
    mainContainer.appendChild(qContainer);
  }
  console.log(mainContainer.outerHTML.split("><").join(">\n<"));
```

```css
/* The visible letters for the list items come from here, not from the script */
ol{ list-style-type: upper-alpha; }
.question{ margin-top: 25px; }
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer"></div>
```